# Threejs css3 renderer causes depth problems on Android 4.0+

Tags: javascript, css, three.js

I'm creating a fairly simple 3D environment intended to run on mobile phones. To do this I am using three.js and the CSS3 renderer. I'm using jpgs for all the elements and then adding them to a 3D object. Here's a example:

```
var alley1LeftWall = document.createElement('div');
var alley1LeftImg = document.createElement('img');

alley1LeftWall.style.background = 'rgba(0,0,0,1)';
alley1LeftWall.id = 'alley1LeftWall';
alley1LeftWall.style.width = '1000px';
alley1LeftWall.style.height = '200px';

alley1LeftImg.src = 'img/alley1_left_wall.jpg';

alley1LeftWall.appendChild(alley1LeftImg);


var alley1LeftWall3d = new THREE.CSS3DObject(alley1LeftWall);
alley1LeftWall3d.position.x = -50;
alley1LeftWall3d.position.y = 0;
alley1LeftWall3d.position.z = -700;
alley1LeftWall3d.rotation.x = 0;
alley1LeftWall3d.rotation.y = (Math.PI/180)*90;
alley1LeftWall3d.rotation.z = 0;
```

Think of the 3D environment like the classic Wolfenstein game.

The experience runs perfectly on the iPhone5, but when I test on an Android device I encounter a few depth problems. Far walls will pop over the foreground during the animation and flicker in and out depth.

During my research of this problem all I can really find out is that Android does have some z-index issues but I'm not sure that is the issue here, as threejs uses css3 3D for depth.

I went on the threejs IRC chat room and asked this question but didn't really get anywhere, most people are understandably interested in WebGL rather than the CSS3 renderer.

As anybody experienced this before? Is this a specific limitation of Android phones?

Thanks.

EDIT:
Chrome v18 on mobile has major issues with CSS3D translations. It's seems like a known bug, http://krpano.com/docu/html5/#androidchrome.

Still struggling with the standard browser on Android. Still very buggy but not nearly as bad as Chrome v18 was.